# How to set this mysql parameter --ssl-mode=DISABLED for mysql on knex?

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I want to set this parameter to create a connection to the database, how can I do this with knex?   ssl=false, does not seem to work.

and the only way I can connect to the db is with --ssl-mode=DISABLED when I use

`mysql -h <host> -P <port> -u"user" -p"password" <db-name> --ssl-mode=DISABLED`

```
 {
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    password,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    // --ssl-mode=DISABLED

}
```

Comment: you don't need it, obly if you want ssl you need to add the options https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#ssl-options

Comment: when I remove the parameter --ssl-mode=DISABLED from the mysql command I am unable to connect to the db, that's why I wanted to add it to the KnexConfigs

Comment: when I don't add --ssl-mode=DISABLED to the command it gives me "SSL connection error"

Comment: there doesn't seem to be such an option, as the server should offer it. Write a issue on github https://github.com/knex/knex/issues, or check the configuration of the server of course you can generate a ssl key and use that to connect